# Getting the response back from the queue to the same server which made the request

Tags: java, queue, jms, activemq-classic

I have an application and multiple instances of it is running on different servers. One server is publishing a message to a Topic. Multiple queues will get the message and once it its processed response will be put in another queue.

All the instances of the initiating application is subscribed to this queue. How can I make sure that the same application instance which made this request is getting the response from queue.

At present out of the multiple instances, random one is picking up. But I want to get it at the instance where it is originated.

Comment: Just curious. If you want the publisher to process the message i.e. the originating instance also has to process the message, then why do you want to queue them in the first place.

Comment: Here the originating instance has to return that response to UI. ie A request comes from UI via REST API to one of the instance, it will queue the message and once the request is processed it will be in a queue where all the instances of requesting application is listening to. If I get it on the initiating instance then only I can return it to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Use JMS properties to identify the source of the originating message, have the response include the same property, and have the original producers use message selectors to only pick up the appropriate messages.  I've used this technique numerous times, and it's very efficient (though likely different providers probably have different overhead).

Let selectors be your friend.

Comment: I am passing the Instance identifier in JMSCorelationId and its coming back to the final queue. I could apply selectors with JMS. Now I am using Camel and specify endpoint uri to it. How can I specify the selector for JMScorelationIS in the endpoint uri as parameter?

Comment: I think this will do the selector job :  selector=JMSCorrelationID%3D'Server01'